# Is there an elegant way in C# to compare all elements in a 2D array to a single value and return a bool array of same size?

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, matrix

Say I have a matrix (2D array in c#) A of size 3x3 in Matlab:

> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];

If I want to compare all values to a single value and return a logical matrix (bool array) of the same size, I simply do this:

> B = A > 3

And the result is:

> B = [0 0 0; 1 1 1; 1 1 1]

So my question is: Does C# has a similar procedure already implemented or is there a way to do the same without having to compare each element of matrix A to the value (3) inside a nested for loop?

I ask this because I'm working with fairly large arrays in C# (say `500x500`) in which I need to do the procedure above multiple times throughout my code and I think this might cause perfomance issues if not handled properly.

Comment: There has to be a loop anyway, whether you write it or someone else. There may be a shorthand version with LINQ depending on the specific data structure (jagged vs multidimensional array etc) but there's still going to be looping.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Math.net library which you can download and use from nuget package management. It is a wrapper package which might not give you any difference with performance, but you would have pre-defined methods (already tested and verified) to achieve your task.

For example, if you want to multiple two Dense matrix, you would already have a predefined method in this library.

Comment: These in no way, without comparing all elements. All Libraries are optimized to do this task

Comment: This is not really a specific answer for this specific problem, rather a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can run/test [below answer here at DotnetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KAwmFr).

The short answer:

```
var results = from item in input.Cast<int>()
        select item > 3? 1: 0;
```

Full answer:

```
public static T[,] Make2DArray<T>(T[] input, int height, int width)
{
    T[,] output = new T[height, width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            output[i, j] = input[i * width + j];                
            Console.Write(output[i, j] + "\t" );
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
    return output;
}

public static void Main()
{       
    // Two-dimensional array.
    int[,] input = new int[,] { { 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
    var results = from item in input.Cast<int>()
            select item > 3? 1: 0;      
    foreach(var item in  results)
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    var output = Make2DArray(results.ToArray(), 3,3);
}

//Output:
0    0    0    
1    1    1    
1    1    1
```